# Groups whose finite index subgroups are isomorphic

Tags: gr.group-theory

I am looking for examples of the following situation:

$G$ is an infinite group. Every two finite index proper subgroups of $G$ are isomorphic.

The only examples that I have now are (1) $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for $n$ any cardinal number, (2) groups that have at most one proper infinite subgroup of finite index (thanks to Sasha Anan'in's and  Derek Holt's comments), (3) direct product of groups in (1) and (2).

1. Are these the only examples for the above situation?
2. Is there a classification for groups with this property?
3. Can we find examples with various properties? For example, $G$ is not amenable, etc.

Any related reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Take any simple infinite group.

Comment: @SashaAnan'in: Yes indeed they satisfy the assumption too. Let me modify the question to discard this class.

Comment: More generally, perhaps you should discard all groups with at most one proper finite index subgroups. But you still get examples like direct products of infinite simple groups with ${\mathbb Z}^n$.

Comment: As Derek Holt observed, there are plenty slight modifications of infinite simple groups.

Comment: The word "proper" in the question is quite unnatural, it would be more natural to ask about groups with all finite index subgroups isomorphic to avoid nonsense discussion.

Comment: @YvesCornulier: Even if we omit the word "proper", still Sasha's comment is valid and we have to exclude simple groups.

Comment: @Vahid: yes, but you omit the word "proper" you get two classes: those with no proper subgroups of finite index (aperiodic groups, including infinite simple groups and many more) and those with infinitely many finite index subgroups.

Comment: Anyway here's an example: the semidirect product $\mathbf{Q}[t,t^{-1},u]\rtimes\mathbf{Z}$ where the generator of $\mathbf{Z}$ acts by multiplication by $t$. On the other hand I don't know if there's a single non-abelian infinite residually finite group with your property.

Comment: I think that residually finite is the only interesting case. It took a long time to give a non virtually nilpotent group with a proper finite index subgroup isomorphic to it.

Comment: Lamplighters and solvable Baumslag-solvable groups have lots of finite index subgroups isomorphic to the whole group using the automaton representation.

Comment: But asking for all is very strong.

Comment: @Yves: I do not see how your example works. What is the role of variable $u$? Could you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I agree. But I was a little uncertain about the question and I thought there might be a very simple answer which describes all cases.

Comment: The variable $u$ makes the module of infinite rank over $\mathbf{Q}[t^{\pm 1}]$, with basis $(u^n)_{n\ge 0}$, so that this does not change when replacing $\mathbf{Z}$ by a finite index subgroup.

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh what is the $C^{*}$ algebraic interpretation for $C_{red}^{*}(G)$, where $G$ is a group which satisfies in your assumption?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I haven't thought about it yet. This question came to my mind from a purely algebraic point of view related to $\mathbb{Z}$.