# Pseudo-Surface Groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a residually finite group, and suppose that for every finite index subgroup $U$ of $G$ we have:

$$d(U) = 2[G : U] + 2.$$

Is $G$ necessarily a surface group?

Here $d(U)$ is the least cardinality of a generating set of the group $U$.

It is also interesting to ask the same question with $d(U)$ replaced by $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}} (H_1(U,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: Your formula is for $G$ of genus 2? it does not work for other surface groups (the right-hand term does not depend on $d(G$... just taking $U=G$  yields $d(G)=4$.)

Comment: @YCor you are right. I am restricting to a special case.

Comment: So the question is whether $G$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1$ of a closed surface of Euler characteristic $-2$ (the orientable one, of genus 2, or the non-orientable one, quotient of a genus 3 surface by a fixed-point-free orientation-reversing involution).

Comment: @YCor I thought only about the orientable one - with presentation $\langle x,y,z,w \ | \ [x,y][z,w] =1 \rangle$. Is there any other group?

Comment: *Is there any other group?* The answer is already in my previous comment: yes.

Comment: @YCor thanks for your comments! They were very helpful!

Comment: Could you then just write for me a presentation for that other (non-orientable) group?

Comment: Non-orientable surface groups have a presentation $\langle x,y,z,w|x^2y^2z^2w^2=1\rangle$. You can replace a pair of squares by a commutator, unless you lose the last square this way, the isomorphism type of the group does not change.

Comment: In the pro-$p$ world there are examples different from surface groups. If $G$ is a 4-generated Demuskin group, then every closed subgroup $U$ needs $2(G:U)+2$ generators. Demuskin groups generalize the pro-$p$ completion of surface groups, as they have presentations of the form $\langle x,y,z,w|x^{p^n}[x,y][z,w]=1\rangle$.

Comment: Some months ago, I have asked a related question and never got an answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/238426/groups-whose-finite-index-subgroups-of-fixed-index-are-isomorphic

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta Actually, you can't use Demushkin groups for my second question because you have torsion in their abelianization (so you must take a pro-$p$ surface group). Do you have any other examples in the pro-$p$ case? Note that by a theorem of Dummit-Labute your example has to have more than one relation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, I do not know whether Demushkin groups answer your first question, as e.g. $\langle x,y,z,w|x^4[x,y][z,w]\rangle$ has subgroups of mixed index as well. May be you should ask GAP about the number of generators of subgroups of index 6 in such a group.